# Installing Ruby on Ubuntu 10.10 using RVM, problem with gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I've decided to start fresh with ubuntu 10.10. 
I started with installing git and then installing rvm from the git repo. everything worked 
fine and I compiled and install ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.2
the gem is also installed and I run gem -v
but when run gem list or gem install rake I get the following error

```
ERROR:  Loading command: list (LoadError)
no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::ListCommand
```

any idea how to solve this issue?
I also tried `sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential libpq-dev` with no luck

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using rvm you can simple do steps that are shown here: [link text](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/)

`$ rvm pkg install zlib` (or, older format, `rvm package install zlib` )

```
$ rvm remove 1.9.2
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-zlib-dir=~/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: You are my personal hero today.

Comment: In some cases you many need to set ruby default for rvm. Using above example, the command for that would be `rvm alias create default ruby-1.9.2`

Answer (score 7):

Or if using rvm, just re-install the ruby version once you have zlib1g-dev installed.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following in your Ruby source after installing zlib1g-dev:

```
cd ext/zlib
ruby extconf.rb
make
sudo make install
```

Also see: https://rbjl.janlelis.com/19-rubybuntu-1-installing-ruby-and-rails-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

First implode your rvm and try following steps in this link. might help you
This might help you. http://www.jaikeerthi.in/2010/11/install-rails-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Please also see https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/420

I went through personally and verified installation capabilities on multiple distributions and platforms to make sure the process worked as expected.

The key thing to take away from this is: before you attempt to install **any** Ruby versions under RVM, you should **always** read the

```
rvm notes
```

command as this contains information that is displayed based on the platform you are currently running. This gives you the list of minimalistic requirements for all versions of a specific Ruby that you will need to install from your package manager. Keep in mind that if you plan on using several different versions like, say, an RBX ruby, an MRI ('normal' ruby), or a REE then you should install all those additional prerequisites taking care to carefully read the notes list.

**NOTE:** When you first install, or after every upgrade, be sure to execute:

```
rvm notes
```

each and every time you upgrade as we place important information regarding gotchas and requirements, as well as workarounds, here. We will be creating a 'issues' command for RVM shortly.